# Building a SpreadsheetApp Function Call Based on an Array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

In Goole Apps Script, when a SpreadsheetApp line can take multiple function calls is it possible to build that function call based on a variable number? For example, you can have multiple calls to setTextStyle in one line. If I have an array that holds the parameters for this function, can I base the number of function calls based on the length of the array?

To illustrate, if the length of my array is 1 I want the following:

```
value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
             .setText(a)
             .setTextStyle(arr[0][0], arr[0][1], bold)
             .build();
```

But if the length of my array is 2 I want the following:

```
value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
             .setText(a)
             .setTextStyle(arr[0][0], arr[0][1], bold)
             .setTextStyle(arr[1][0], arr[1][1], bold)
             .build();
```

In each of these, a is my text, arr is my array and bold is a variable holding the command for bolding text.

Comment: For the most part Google Apps Script behaves like Javascript.  If you wish to  know how functions work read your favorite Javascript for ECMA Script 2015 and that should tell you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of setting multiple rich text formats from an array.

`setTextStyle()` returns a `RichTextValueBuilder` which can be chained to another `setTextStyle()`.

```
function setRichText() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let a = "Hello World";
    let bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
    let italic = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setItalic(true).build();
    let arr = [[0,5,bold],[6,11,italic]];
    let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(a);
    arr.forEach( value => {
        richText = richText.setTextStyle(value[0],value[1],value[2]);
      }
    );
    sheet.getRange("A1").setRichTextValue(richText.build());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [RichTextValueBuilder.setText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setText(String))
- [RichTextValueBuilder.setTextStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setTextStyle(Integer,Integer,TextStyle))
- [RichTextValueBuilder.build()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#build())
- [Range.setRichTextValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setRichTextValue(RichTextValue))